# Subscribing to Exchange calendar in GSuite Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-workspace-for-business

I've got two calendars that I'm trying to synchronize: Google Calendar on GSuite (main) and Exchange-based with access through EWS (secondary).
To make it a bit easier I only need one-way synchronization (secondary to main).

For now I've configured GSuite Calendar Interop option and I can view free/busy status for my secondary calendar (while adding events) but still can't subscribe to it (can't add it to "my calendars" section).
The interesting part here is that I can do that via mobile application so hopefully it's also possible via website.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to sync Microsoft Exchange Calendar with G Suite Google Calendar you could use G Suite Migration for Microsoft® Exchange (GSMME), a utility that migrates mail, calendar, and contact data from your Exchange server or mail from a G Suite account. You can find the corresponding documentation regarding G Suite Migration for Microsoft Exchange by following this link [https://support.google.com/a/answer/6305431?hl=en&authuser=1&ref_topic=4454645 .](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6305431?hl=en&authuser=1&ref_topic=4454645%20.)

Additionally, you can do it from your Google admin dashboard by

1. Navigate to https://admin.google.com
2. Click on Data Migration
3. Select the migrate Calendar data option
4. And finally your migration source etc.

I hope this helps!